# My Google plus one button is showing up in Arabic when it works on other domains?

Tags: javascript, html, google-plus

I have the Google Plus code on my website, and it is showing up in Arabic when the same code is working on my other domains. I have searched for the answer to this problem but can't find an answer to it.

You can see what I am dealing with here; http://www.primetimeprint.com  The plus 1 button is at the very bottom. I have cleared my browser and still keep getting the same thing. I have also tried multiple browsers; Chrome, Firefox, etc.  But it is acting the same on this website, and the most confusing thing is that it is working fine on my other domains when the code is exactly the same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When creating the code for the +1 button, you can explicitly set the language.

Looking through the code of your page, this seems to be set to Arabic. This is the script you currently have in there:

```
window.___gcfg = {lang: 'ar'};
(function() 
{var po = document.createElement("script");
po.type = "text/javascript"; po.async = true;po.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js";
var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
```

The offending line here is

```
window.___gcfg = {lang: 'ar'};
```

This makes your text appear in Arabic. Changing it to UK English using

```
window.___gcfg = {lang: 'en-GB'};
```

or removing it completely (which defaults to US English I think) should solve that. Or simply re-generate the appropriate code here: https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/